# Lookahead regex produces unexpected group

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract a page name and query string from a URL which should not contain `.html`

Here is an example code in Java:

```
public class TestRegex { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/test/(((?!\\.html).)+)\\?(.+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/test/page?param=value");
        System.out.println(matcher.matches());
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

By running this code one can get the following output:

> true
>   page
>   e

What's wrong with my regex so the second group contains the letter `e` instead of `param=value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing:

```
Pattern.compile("/test/(((?!\\.html).)+)\\?(.+)")
//                     ^^            ^ ^   ^  ^
//                     ||            | |   |  |
//                     |+------2-----+ |   +-3+
//                     |               |  
//                     +-------1-------+
```

Try:

```
Pattern.compile("/test/((?:(?!\\.html).)+)\\?(.+)")
//                     ^                 ^   ^  ^
//                     |                 |   |  |
//                     |                 |   +-2+
//                     |                 |  
//                     +--------1--------+
```

In other words: `(?:...)` makes it a non-capturing group.